# Mechanics for fire arrow/pyrotechnics

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, equipment

So my lovable halfling bard has the spells [Pyrotechnics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/pyrotechnics/) and [Spark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spark/). He also has a plain old regular small shortbow.

What is the easiest and cheapest way to set an arrow on fire, or attach something to an arrow, and shoot as far as I can, and then use it as the component for pyrotechnics?

Answer (score 6):

### 5 PA per arrow

Buy some [Incendiary arrows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/arrow-incendiary) (20 arrows/bolts for 10 po). They last 2 round once they have been lighted so you should have enough time.

**HOW TO :**

1. Use spark (or tindertwigs) to light some. You still have a move action to get your bow or to do something else.
2. Fire your arrow at the ground (AC 5)
3. Cast Pyrotechnics
4. Profit.

### Or you know...

1. Keep a lighted torch with you.
2. Throw it
3. Cast Pyrotechnics
4. Profit.

Comment: If the person firing the arrow is different from the person casting pyrotechnics you could ready an action to cast pyrotechnics on the arrow while it is in flight. This lets you A) do it all in one turn and B) Still use pyrotechnics on an arrow in terrain that would extinguish it (i.e. firing over water)

Answer (score 1):

1 flask of oil, 1 sp.

Prep a bunch of arrows with old rags tied on them. 1cp (or 0cp if found items)

Before firing, dip arrows in oil.

Then noch arrow, light with spark and fire.  Then use pyrotechnics.